# Get height of div once javascript dynamic content is loaded into it

Tags: jquery, dom, html, height, var

I just realized I messed up on my last question.

I'm using this script below to get the dynamic height on DIV#tweet-area and insert that height into CSS.

```
    var tweetheight = $("#tweet-area").height();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: tweetheight});
```

It works a beaut but I just realized the height it's getting, is the height of the div before my twitter content is loaded. My twitter content is generated by a jQuery plugin, see below.

I'm using this jQuery twitter plugin - [tweet.seaofclouds.com/jquery.tweet.js](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/jquery.tweet.js)

And loading the script like this -

```
    $("#latest-tweet").tweet({
        count: 1,
        username: ["motocomdigital"],
        loading_text: "searching twitter...",
    });
```

Im loading the tweets into DIV#latest-tweet which is inside DIV#tweet-area. See below

```
    <div id="tweet-area" class="clearfix">
        <div id="latest-tweet"></div>   
    </div>
```

Ive tried adding my height script after the twitter script but still gets the same height :/

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#latest-tweet").tweet({
                        count: 1,
                        username: ["motocomdigital"],
                        loading_text: "searching twitter..."
                });

                var tweetheight = $("#tweet-area").height();
                $("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: tweetheight});

        });
    </script>
```

Any help would be awesome as this is a little expert for me. Thank so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#latest-tweet").tweet({
                        count: 1,
                        username: ["motocomdigital"],
                        loading_text: "searching twitter..."
                }).bind("loaded", function(){
                        tweetheight = $("#tweet-area").height();
                        $("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: tweetheight});
                });
        });
    </script>
```

This implements a poorly documented caller in the plugin you got, which is a call to the `loaded` handler after the code is run. Good luck!

Comment: Perfect dude, thanks so much man! - Thanks for taking a look, I wouldn't of found that handler - though I've never used the .bind before but am sure to now.

Answer (score 2):

The seaofclouds plugin doesn't have a callback, instead it has a `loaded` event which is fired when the loading of tweets has completed.

Therefore the following should work for you:

```
$("#latest-tweet").tweet({
    count: 1,
    username: ["motocomdigital"],
    loading_text: "searching twitter..."
})
.bind("loaded", function() {
    var tweetheight = $("#tweet-area").height();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: tweetheight});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

on line `229` of the plugin you read

```
$(widget).trigger("loaded")
```

this triggers the event `loaded` on the div you binded tweet on. So you could do

```
$("#latest-tweet").tweet({    
    // options
}).bind("loaded", function(){
    // calc height
});
```

Comment: Yeah just had a look inside side the pluggin - thank you for explain this to me, helped alot!

Comment: hello, I know this is a bit cheeky, but as your familiar with my problem earlier, could you please take a look at this [http://goo.gl/NWNx8](http://goo.gl/NWNx8) - can donate via paypal if you can help :)

Comment: Hi try this as rewrote question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176034/iscroll-4-stops-working-because-of-container-css-created-by-javascript-jquery - thanks