# iScroll 4 stops working because of container CSS created by javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iscroll4

I'm running iScroll 4 inside a DIV, but the DIV's height is generated dynamically, and screws up iScroll

```
    <script src="js/iscroll/iscroll.js?v4"></script>
    <script>
        var myScroll;
        function loaded() {
            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper-sidebar-left');

            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper-sidebar-right');

            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');

        }

        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

    </script>
```

If I give iScrolls containing DIV a hard coded height then it works fine.

But it's a dynamic height created by javascript. And iScroll ignores it. But when you adjust the viewport size on a desktop browser, its kicks in and works.

This is the  script creating the dynamic height.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#latest-tweet").tweet({
                    count: 1,
                    username: ["motocomdigital"],
                    loading_text: "searching twitter..."
            }).bind("loaded", function(){
                    var tweetheight = $("#tweet-area").height();
                    $("#sidebar-wrapper").css({ bottom: tweetheight });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Ignore the twitter script - it's after the binded function which is determining the height of the containing DIV.

The height on the 'scroller's' containing DIV is determined by these CSS values: top: 0px and the 'bottom' value. But the bottom CSS value is dynamic.

See live project here - this is when it's broken, click menu to see the broken scrollers in the sidebar.

[Broken scrollers](http://www.motocomdigital.co.uk/development/headache/dynamic)

Then see the same project below but with a hard coded bottom CSS value added in the head, and the script removed. And this works fine.

[Working scrollers](http://www.motocomdigital.co.uk/development/headache/non-dynamic)

Which means iScroll is ignoring the bottom CSS value *(but it starts working when you adjust the viewport size, but no good on a device)*

Any help would be so appreciated

Thanks, Josh

---

**UPDATE, THIS WORKS - BUT WILL IT WORK EVERYTIME**?

```
    <script>

        var myScroll;
        function loaded() {
            setTimeout(function () {

                myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper-sidebar-left', {
                    scrollbarClass: 'sub-scrollbar',
                    useTransform: false,
                        onBeforeScrollStart: function (e) {
                            var target = e.target;
                            while (target.nodeType != 1) target = target.parentNode;
                            if (target.tagName != 'SELECT' && target.tagName != 'INPUT' && target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA')
                            e.preventDefault();

                    }
                });

                myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper-sidebar-right');

            }, 1000);

            myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');

        }
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic footer height via jQuery breaking iScroll 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175182/dynamic-footer-height-via-jquery-breaking-iscroll-4)

Comment: Was this your final solution as I'm struggling with the exact same issue?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the `refresh()` method for iScroll?

You do need to change you code a bit because you use the `myScroll` for multiple elements. So for example if you have 1 element that needs to be iScrolled:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
  var myScroll;
  function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('sidebar-wrapper');
  }
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

  $(function() {
    $("#latest-tweet").tweet({
      count: 1,
      username: ["motocomdigital"],
      loading_text: "searching twitter..."
    }).bind("loaded", function(){
      // as described on the "Methods" section on http://cubiq.org/iscroll
      setTimeout(function () { myScroll.refresh() }, 0);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel - this put me on the right track, this is what I did after reading the cubiqs docs. See update in question. It works, but would say a timer is rough? Can DOM loading elements differ in time depending on connection? Or would you say what's I've done is full proof?

Comment: we'll the only time you have to refresh the iScroll component is when the element is resized isn't it? so as in my example code i've placed the setTimeout within the bind("loaded") event of the twitter plugin

Comment: ahh OK i'll have another go but I cudnt get yours to work first time round - let me have another look

Comment: I'm confused i how I would make this work on multiple iScroll elements? I can't get it to work with my current scripts. I'm loading jQuery in the footer and iScroll in the header. Sorry to be so useless..